# Pandas query shows only columns in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

Could enyone explain me why code below shows only colum names while dataframe is filled with 16k rows

```
nan_val_array = data.query("year_of_release.isna()")

for nan_val in nan_val_array:
     print(nan_val)
```

**the output is**:

- name
- platform
- year_of_release
- genre
- na_sales
- eu_sales
- jp_sales
- other_sales
- critic_score
- user_score
- rating

**the actual data look like**:

| name | platform | year_of_release | genre | na_sales | eu_sales | jp_sales | other_sales | critic_score | user_score | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Madden NFL 2004 | PS2 | NaN | Sports | 4.26 | 0.26 | 0.01 | 0.71 | 94.0 | 8.5 | E |
| Madden NFL 2004 | XB | 2003.0 | Sports | 1.02 | 0.02 | 0.00 | 0.05 | 92.0 | 8.3 | E |
| Madden NFL 2004 | GC | 2003.0 | Sports | 0.40 | 0.10 | 0.00 | 0.01 | 94.0 | 7.7 | E |
| Madden NFL 2004 | GBA | 2003.0 | Sports | 0.22 | 0.08 | 0.00 | 0.01 | 70.0 | 6.6 | E |

I don't understand why I can't iterate through my selection ...

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Comment: It is similar to looping by dictionary. When you loop through a dictionary, you only loop over the keys. Similarly, you only loop over the columns by dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected, reason is if loop by `DataFrame` it working same like looping by columns names:

```
for nan_val in nan_val_array:
    print(nan_val)
```

is same:

```
for nan_val in nan_val_array.columns:
    print(nan_val)
```

So if need loop by `Series` need:

```
for nan_val in nan_val_array:
    print (nan_val_array[nan_val])
```

or with [`DataFrame.items`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.items.html):

```
for name, val in nan_val_array.items():
    print (val)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the latest pandas version, the code is working well to filter the **rows**, not columns:

```
data.query("year_of_release.isna()")
```

You could also use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
data.loc[lambda d: d['year_of_release'].isna()]
```

Output:

```
              name platform  year_of_release   genre  na_sales  eu_sales  jp_sales  other_sales  critic_score  user_score rating
0  Madden NFL 2004      PS2              NaN  Sports      4.26      0.26      0.01         0.71          94.0         8.5      E
```

If you want to keep only the non-NA columns, rather use:

```
data.dropna(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
              name platform   genre  na_sales  eu_sales  jp_sales  other_sales  critic_score  user_score rating
0  Madden NFL 2004      PS2  Sports      4.26      0.26      0.01         0.71          94.0         8.5      E
1  Madden NFL 2004       XB  Sports      1.02      0.02      0.00         0.05          92.0         8.3      E
2  Madden NFL 2004       GC  Sports      0.40      0.10      0.00         0.01          94.0         7.7      E
3  Madden NFL 2004      GBA  Sports      0.22      0.08      0.00         0.01          70.0         6.6      E
```

Then if you want to iterate:

```
for k, row in data.query("year_of_release.isna()").iterrows():
    print(row)
```